# How i can get the probability of $P(X = 5)$ and $P(X=6)$

Tags: combinatorics, random-variables

I have this statement:

> A bag contains $5$ chips numbered from $5$ to $9$. If $3$ chips are taken one
>   after another without replacement and the random variable $X$ is defined
>   as "the lowest value of the chips extracted ", determine if is false or true that $P(X = 5) = 2 P(X = 6)$

My attempt was:

I know that the possible combinations are $5*4*3 = 60$.

And $P(X = 5)$ means that in the first, second or third extraction the number $5$ was extracted, but i don't know how to get this probability, and same with the probability of $P(X=6)$.

and I do not think the solution is to write the $60$ combinations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, there aren't $60$ cases since the order doesn't matter.  There are only $\binom 53=10$.

Comment: Of course, there is no need to write down all the cases anyway (though that is not difficult).  The event $X=5$ is the same as the event "the $5$ is drawn".  What is the probability that I get the $5$ in three draws without replacement?

Comment: I think the order matter, because when i take $7,6,5$ is a case for $P(X=5)$ and for $6,7,5$ too.

Comment: Yes...which illustrates the fact that the order does not matter.  If I ask which of three people is the shortest, does it matter which order they are standing in?

Comment: @lulu is correct. I have updated my answer to reflect this point as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $X = 5$, the lowest chip must be $5$.
There are exactly $4 * 3 = 12$ ways of picking the other two chips (out of $\{6,7,8,9\}$), but since the lowest chip may be picked in either of the $3$ turns, there are a total of $3 * 12 = 36$ ways of picking the chips such that the lowest one is $5$.

For $X = 6$, the lowest chip must be $6$. There are exactly $3 * 2 = 6$ ways of picking the other two chips (out of $\{7,8,9\}$), but since the lowest chip may be picked in either of the $3$ turns, there are a total of $3 * 6 = 18$ ways of picking the chips such that the lowest one is $6$.

Clearly, the total number of ways to get $X = 5$ is twice that of $X = 6$. You don't even need to compute the exact probabilities and the total number of ways to draw chips ($60$ is correct, by the way). But for completeness, $P(X=5) = 36/60 = 0.6$ and $P(X=6) = 18/60 = 0.3$.

---

You would also reach the same answer if you consider "distinct combinations of chips" instead of "distinct ways of drawing the chips".
As mentioned in @lulu's comment, the total number of combinations is ${5 \choose 3} = 10$.

The number of combinations for $X = 5$ is exactly ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ since you choose $2$ chips out of $\{6,7,8,9\}$.

Similarly, the number of combinations for $X = 6$ is exactly ${3 \choose 2} = 3$ since you choose $2$ chips out of $\{7,8,9\}$.

You get the same exact probabilities: $P(X = 5) = 0.6$ and $P(X = 6) = 0.3$.

Comment: Very thorough answer (+1).  To be clear:  there's nothing wrong with working with the full $60$ ordered triples.  As your calculation shows, you get the same result either way.   It's just not necessary, and years of numerical  programming have drilled into me that you should never work with large collections when a smaller one would do.

Comment: Thank you! I completely agree. Smaller numbers and collections are much easier to deal with.

Comment: what "drawing the chips" means?(im spanish person) Is "writte the chips"?

Comment: It means the sequence in which you pick the chips. For example, $\langle 6,5,7 \rangle$ and $\langle 7,6,5 \rangle$ are two ways of drawing the same combination  $\{ 5,6,7 \}$ of chips.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that